# How do I restrict apache permissions to prevent users accessing code directly?

Tags: apache, security, directory, public, restrict

I have a Laravel project that I have implemented into my organization and I'm having some problems with permissions.

The user regardless of whether logged in or not is able to view directory listings of controllers, storage, providers basically everything.

They can't save it by right clicking but they can click and execute it directly which presents many security problems.

It's not a public facing site but it still needs securing as anyone on the network can technically access this via the url.

How can I secure this?

Please see image below for an example:

[image: Example Directory listing that is not restricted]

Comment: You have probably the Option Indexes set for those/that directory. Just take it out and you should not see directory listing afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Andre Gelinas, it looks like I had some issues with my httpd.conf file.

It had been completely open for some reason allowing all permissions and everyone to access all directories/files.

For those wondering and who also have Laravel projects, the following lines solved my problem.

Note this is based on Windows Apache. If you are using Linux, you will need to replace with Linux paths.

```
#Prevent access to all of mdm3 directory
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/mdm3">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#Except allow the public directory
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/mdm3/public">
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```